# R - Ignore Empty?

Tags: r

To clairify: all I'm looking for is something like an if statement that will somehow ignore the entire add_trace function if the data frame has no rows.

I have the following R code:

```
g <- plot_ly(df, x = ~Day) %>%
  add_trace(data=df[which(df$FcNum==1),], y = ~ProjAmount, name = 'Line 1', hoverinfo = "text", text = ~paste('Projected Amt: ', round(ProjAmount,2)), mode = 'lines', width = 1, connectgaps = "false") %>% 
  add_trace(data=df[which(df$FcNum==2),], y = ~ProjAmount, name = 'Line 2', hoverinfo = "text", text = ~paste('Projected Amt: ', round(ProjAmount,2)), mode = 'lines', width = 1, connectgaps = "false")
```

My data frame looks like this:

```
 Day       Amount    ProjAmt      FcNum     
 1          10.4       55          1         
 1          10.4       37          2        
 2          22.1       55          1         
 2          22.1       37          2        
 3          43.5       55          1        
 3          43.5       37          2        
 4          24.1       55          1        
 4          24.1       55          2        
...         ...        ...
34          37.8       75          1        
34          37.8       99          2        
35          12.8       75          1        
35          12.8       99          2
```

The visualization tool I'm using fails the script when I filter on the FcNum (so when I add a filter to the visual and say "only give me values where FcNum is 1"). The visualization fails because there is no longer a value where FcNum == 2 and it returns the following error message: "Error: Variables must be length 1 or 1."

(so what's happening behind the scenes is it's filtering the data frame to look like this, notice the values in the FcNum column:

```
 Day       Amount    ProjAmt      FcNum    
 1          10.4       55          1        
 2          22.1       55          1        
 3          43.5       55          1        
 4          24.1       55          1        
...         ...        ...
34          37.8       75          1        
35          12.8       75          1
```

In other words, when line number 3 in the code returns no value, it's unable to display the graph because it requires that every variable has a value of 1 or 1.

Is there a function, perhaps in base R that allows me to set an alternative value when the data frame is empty?

I've tried something like

```
add_trace(data=na.omit(df[which(df$FcNum==2),]), y = ~ProjAmount, name = 'Line 2', hoverinfo = "text", text = ~paste('Projected Amt: ', round(ProjAmount,2)), mode = 'lines', width = 1, connectgaps = "false")
```

.... but that didn't work.

Comment: Is `ProjAmount` the same variable as `ProjAmt`?

Comment: @jsb - yes you are correct

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to be working fine (no errors or warnings). I have added `type = "scatter"` and removed `width = 1`.

```
# First 8 rows of your data
df <- structure(list(Day = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), Amount = c(10.4, 
10.4, 22.1, 22.1, 43.5, 43.5, 24.1, 24.1), ProjAmount = c(55L, 
37L, 55L, 37L, 55L, 37L, 55L, 55L), FcNum = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L)), .Names = c("Day", "Amount", "ProjAmount", "FcNum"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

library(plotly)

plot_ly(df, x = ~ Day) %>%
  add_trace(
    data = df[which(df$FcNum == 1), ],
    type = "scatter",  # new line
    y = ~ ProjAmount,
    name = 'Line 1',
    hoverinfo = "text",
    text = ~ paste('Projected Amt: ', round(ProjAmount, 2)),
    mode = 'lines',
    # width = 1,
    connectgaps = "false"
  ) %>%
  add_trace(
    data = df[which(df$FcNum == 2), ],
    type = "scatter",  # new line
    y = ~ ProjAmount,
    name = 'Line 2',
    hoverinfo = "text",
    text = ~ paste('Projected Amt: ', round(ProjAmount, 2)),
    mode = 'lines',
    # width = 1,
    connectgaps = "false"
  )
```

Comment: Yes I know that works in R Studio, but it does not work in the visualization tool I'm using. I am looking to use an if statement as a workaround. I want to tell it not to add_trace if there are no rows in the data.frame with the specified filter context